# How do i make a video loop in HTML?

Tags: html, css, loops, video

I am trying to make a looping iframe with no controls which will loop.

```
<iframe 
src="yeet.mp4" allow="autoplay"  controls="false" loop="true" style="display:visible" id="iframeVideo">
```

But it has controls on and is not looping. How do i fix it?

Comment: try using just loop as an attribute, without "true" attached

Comment: Changed it to this: <iframe 
 src="yeet.mp4"  allow="autoplay"  controls="false"  loop style="display:visible" id="iframeVideo">
</iframe> , did not work

Comment: Try using the HTML video attribute instead <video width="320" height="240" loop><source src="yeet.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Video Format Not Supported</video>

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the loop="true" and leave it as an attribute without value like so

```
 <video loop src="yeet.mp4" autoplay>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Player 
 </video>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to go about this is via Javascript

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

loop ="true" is no longer supported, as is autoplay="autoplay"

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript here